# error: unable to create file bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.tests/testData/ProfilePreferencesTest

Tags: eclipse, git, equinox, p2

I am trying to clone rt.equinox.p2 but every time getting failed with below error

```
error: unable to create file bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.tests/testData/ProfilePreferencesTest/DifferentAgent/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/TestProf
error: unable to create file bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.tests/testData/configAreaToAgent/sharedWithoutBaseAvailable/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/S
fatal: cannot create directory at 'bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.tests/testData/previousConfigurationFinder/testNewBuildInDifferentFolder/differentConfigurations/org.ecl
Unable to checkout '244078186f2065a1458e2ce46deb8021d82a6b05' in submodule path 'rt.equinox.p2'
```

Following the [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Platform_Build#Running_the_build_on_R4_3_1_tag) to clone:

```
git clone -b master --recursive git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git z
```

Comment: Do you get the error when you execute the Git command on the command line? Maybe the path is too long. Which operating system do you have and which version of Git?

Comment: Yes, I got that error, So as a workaround I cloned the project on the root of the drive i.e. c:\. Also if u see my clone URL above I renamed it with z, so my outcome is C:/z. This is working for me

Answer (score 1):

The paths truncated to the same length in the error message indicating that the **overall path length is too long** (probably you are using Windows which has such a limitation).

As a workaround you can try one of the following:

- Use the root directory (or a subdirectory with a short name) as the location for the local repository
- Use Eclipse (EGit) to clone the repository (the path length limitation only exists on the command line)